# How to place image over image?

Tags: html, css

I am working for responsive site. I want to place a small image over large image. Small image should be placed exactly center of this large image. I can't take large image as background of my page. It should be inside div. How?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/TkG8F/)

```
//code
<div class="text-center">
    <img id="draggable1" class="img-responsive" src="http://photos.foter.com/a266/freestanding-wood-and-wire-pet-gate-size-21-width-narrow-span-2658163_300x300.jpg">
       <img class="heartimg" src="http://gorgeousme.co/media/19340/heart_50x42.jpg"/>
    </img>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need this to work for any size of image or will the "background" image always be the same size?

Comment: Will the image always be the same size? Are you going to want to work it out manually everytime? [Would you prefer javascript to work it for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/TkG8F/2/) Going to need a few more details.

Comment: @MLeFevre image size varies as this is for responsive site.

Answer (score 3):

Use absolute positioning on the heart img

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/TkG8F/4/)

**CSS**

```
.text-center {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
}

.text-center img {
    display: block;
}

.text-center .heartimg {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-25px; /* half of it's height */
    margin-left:-21px; /* half of it's width */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<img>` element cannot contain other elements inside. So you can't do something like `<img><img/></img>`

Nest both images under the same div and use `position: absolute;` and `position: relative` to align your image.

Here's a **[Kitten-based example](http://jsfiddle.net/tF2BZ/)**:

#### HTML

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img class="largeImage" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/600?ext=.jpg" alt="Large kitten"/>
    <img class="smallImage" src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50?ext.jpg" alt="Tiny kitten"/>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.text-center {
    display: inline-block; /* Inline block to match large image dimensions */
    position: relative;
}

.smallImage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px; /* Half the image's size. */
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS position** to achieve what you want.

[In MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)  you can retrieve information about different CSS position and its uses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle, you can add the following css class and the heart image will be on top of the other image:

```
.heartimg {
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    left: -55px
}
```

Basically by positioning "relative" you can move the heart image relative to where it normally would have shown. An example fiddle with that working is here: http://jsfiddle.net/du84q/ Best of luck!

**Note:** As others have noted you shouldn't be nesting the "img" tag either. Browsers tend to ignore this, but it doesn't strictly do you any good.